# Hide frame msc package

Tags: msc

I would like to hide/remove the frame around my message sequence charts I create using the `msc` package. The code for my chart:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{msc}

\begin{document}

\begin{msc}{Hello world}
    \declinst{compA}{}{A}
    \declinst{compB}{}{B}
    \declinst{compC}{}{C}
    \mess{Call\_A}{envleft}{compA}
    \nextlevel
    \mess{Call\_B}{compA}{compB}
    \nextlevel
    \mess{Call\_C}{compB}{compC}
    \nextlevel
    \nextlevel
    \mess{Reply\_C}{compC}{compB}
    \nextlevel
    \mess{VoidReply}{compB}{compA}
    \nextlevel
    \mess{VoidReply}{compA}{envleft}
\end{msc}

\end{document}
```

The resulting figure looks like this:

[image]

Again, the idea is to remove the frame around the figure. I have looked into the package manual, but couldn't find it and I've looked around this site to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch the frame on an off using `\drawframe{yes}` and `\drawframe{no}` (or any other value for `no`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{msc}
\drawframe{no}% switch of msc frame
\begin{document}

\begin{msc}{Hello world}
    \declinst{compA}{}{A}
    \declinst{compB}{}{B}
    \declinst{compC}{}{C}
    \mess{Call\_A}{envleft}{compA}
    \nextlevel
    \mess{Call\_B}{compA}{compB}
    \nextlevel
    \mess{Call\_C}{compB}{compC}
    \nextlevel
    \nextlevel
    \mess{Reply\_C}{compC}{compB}
    \nextlevel
    \mess{VoidReply}{compB}{compA}
    \nextlevel
    \mess{VoidReply}{compA}{envleft}
\end{msc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Schweinebacke
when I was typing the answer, there was no answer in the page but when I posted, I realized that you've posted a minute before. such a coincidence!

Comment: @javadr: Shit happens. I think, you could delete your answer, if you do not have any additional information to add. But, wait, I could up-vote it … Done. ;-)

Comment: @Schweinebacke Appreciate your concern. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just put the following command in your document.

```
\drawframe{no}
```

It causes the msc package doesn't show any frame around the diagram, if you want to turn it on, simply use ‍`\drawframe{yes}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{msc}

\begin{document}

\drawframe{no}
\begin{msc}{Hello world}
    \declinst{compA}{}{A}
    \declinst{compB}{}{B}
    \declinst{compC}{}{C}
    \mess{Call\_A}{envleft}{compA}
    \nextlevel
    \mess{Call\_B}{compA}{compB}
    \nextlevel
    \mess{Call\_C}{compB}{compC}
    \nextlevel
    \nextlevel
    \mess{Reply\_C}{compC}{compB}
    \nextlevel
    \mess{VoidReply}{compB}{compA}
    \nextlevel
    \mess{VoidReply}{compA}{envleft}
\end{msc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You were 2 minutes to late. ;-)